# How to get selected date from html element where input type=date using javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>

function datechecker()
 {
      /* Here,How can i display selected date*/
 }
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  
<form method="POST" role="form" name="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h2>Please select datey</h2>
  <input type="date" id="jsdate"  name="txtdate">
  <input type="submit" onclick="datechecker()" value="Check">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I have defined `input type=date` to select date....and i want to **display that selected date using javascript** only....how can i do it??

Answer (score 1):

```js
function datechecker(){
/* Here,How can i display selected date*/
event.preventDefault(); // remove this line in your code.
console.log(jsdate.value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  
<form method="POST" role="form" name="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h2>Please select datey</h2>
  <input type="date" id="jsdate"  name="txtdate">
  <input type="submit" onclick="datechecker()" value="Check">


  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes it is working ..and can i check that like..user must be 18 year old as on 01-05-2018...if it is possible than please provide me code for it